# Include opencv shared object in a Python project

Tags: python, macos, opencv, intellij-idea, pycharm

I am trying to build the Python project [openface](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface), the project includes [cv2](http://opencv.org/)  though I have a strong feeling this problem has nothing to do with [openface](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface) and [cv2](http://opencv.org/) and more with me not understanding the Python development environment enough.

I am running on Mac OSX with El-Capitan, and am using Intellij but I have also tried PyCharm, which also comes from Jetbrains.

The issue is:
I have successfully compiled and installed [cv2](http://opencv.org/) on my machine and it is located at: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
Meaning it is a shared object, but from my understanding it should still work.

I've added this so file to the Python SDK and installed it (at least I think I have).
This is a screenshot from Intellij:
[image]

And this is a screenshot from PyCharm:
[image]

And, yet, after I apply the changes:

```
import cv2
```

Is still not recognised in both Intellij and PyCharm.

How can I add this shared object to my Python project?

Many thanks in advance